# Confused about Jquery load

Tags: html, jquery

May someone tell me why does the content of q.txt not get loaded to the div with the class name "content".  q.txt is a local file

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {
          $(".content").load("q.txt");
      });
    </script>
```

```
      <div id="content">
        <div class="content">
          <h2>aaaa</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Have you checked the console (F12 in the browser) for errors?  eg 404 not found...  *"a local file"* implies (to me) that your html/js is also "local", and some js doesn't run for `file://` sites, giving errors in the console.

Comment: @freedomn-m thanks! I just checked the console and it gives such a error " from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https"

Comment: Which you should find numerous solutions to on SO.  Specifically, run your page from a webserver.  You can get lightweight webservers that don't need much installation.